# CakePHP: Find where field is not null

Tags: php, cakephp

I need to select all rows where `User.site_url` is not null. It's simple enough to do this in a regular **MySQL** query but how is this done in **CakePHP**?

The manual mentions the following:

```
array ("not" => array (
        "Post.title" => null
    )
)
```

I have tried the following but it's still returning everything

```
$this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('not' => array('User.site_url'))));
```

Comment: 'conditions' => ["Post.title IS NULL" ] is the way to go here

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I think this is what you mean:

```
$this->User->find('all', array( 
    'conditions' => array('not' => array('User.site_url' => null))
));
```

Comment: I don't believe I missed something like that, thanks to both of the answers!

Comment: Translates to "AND NOT (User.site_url = NULL)".  So I prefer @GwynBleidd answer ['User.site_url IS NOT NULL'].

Comment: Agree with what @FrançoisBreton said except there is one catch: if the field you are filtering by is a virtual field, it will work using the longer `'NOT' => ['field' => null]` convention but not using the `'virtual_field IS NOT NULL'` convetion.

Answer (score 17):

Your just missing the null

```
$this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('not' => array('User.site_url'=>null))));
```

Answer (score 16):

In Cake, a WHERE condition is constructed from 'conditions' element by joining keys and values. That means that you can actually skip providing the keys if you like. E.g.:

```
array('conditions' => array('User.id'=>1))
```

is completely equivalent to

```
array('conditions' => array('User.id = 1'))
```

Essentially, you can solve your problem by just this:

```
$this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.site_url IS NOT NULL')));
```

Answer (score 8):

For simple query:

```
$this->User->find('all', array(
     'conditions' => array(
         'User.site_url IS NOT NULL'
));
```

For cakephp 3.X

```
 $table = TableRegistry::get('Users');
 $assessmentComments = $table
      ->find()
      ->where(function (QueryExpression $exp, Query $q) {
            return $exp->isNotNull('site_url');
        })
      ->all();
```

Comment: IS NOT NULL, and IS NULL is definitely the way to go here.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try this,

```
$this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.site_url <>' => null));
```

This works fine for me..

Answer (score 3):

Please try `''` rather than `null`:

```
$this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.site_url <>' => ''));
```

Comment: Can you please describe what you are trying to do, and the exact problem you are facing? from this one liner it looks like it's telling you to use ''  instead null that you might be using in your query.

Answer (score 1):

This work fine for me:

```
$this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.site_url !=' => null));
```

Answer (score 1):

**this scope is correct!** (ctlockey)

```
$this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('not' => array('User.site_url' =>null))));
```

However I using with different versions of MySql and MariaDb returned inconstant results.
I believe that a little bit of direct sql is not that bad so to ensure the integrity of the return.

Therefore, I did the following:

```
$Obj->find()->where(['field_a IS NULL', 'field_b IS NOT NULL'])->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Its working for me**

```
$this->set('inventory_masters',$this->InventoryMaster->find('all',array('order'=>$orderfinal,'conditions' => array('InventoryMaster.id' => $checkboxid,'not' => array('InventoryMaster.error'=>null)))));
```