# Concise, intuitive description of how PHP manages variable internally?

Tags: php, cakephp

**Background:** I'm using CakePHP for a project and was wondering what happens when I find/save a DB record that has NULL for a column/field.  According to http://goldapplesoftware.ca/blog/2011-09-storing-null-values-database-cakephp and [CakePHP: Find where field is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196969/cakephp-find-where-field-is-not-null) it looks like CakePHP will (generally) translate the MySQL NULL column into PHP's NULL value.  This is great for my intuition (NULL in DB => NULL in PHP), but surprisingly tricky in PHP.

It's tricky because **I want to check if an array slot is defined, but has the value NULL.**

After reading through the thorough-but-confusing http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php, then isset, unset, and several pages on null (including, most usefully, http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) I arrived at more-or-less the same conclusion as [Check if Variable exists and === true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908163/check-if-variable-exists-and-true).  Namely, you can check if a variable is defined (but has the value null) with

```
if (isset($array['x']) && $array['x'] === NULL)
```

(or, for an array:

```
if( array_key_exists('x', $array) && $array['x'] === NULL)
```

)

**My Question:**  I am looking for a concise, hopefully intuitive explanation of how PHP deals with variables internally.

After pondering everything I'd read I realized that the closest mental model I had was JavaScript Scope Chain ([Scope Chain in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484143/scope-chain-in-javascript)).  Defining a variable  in PHP seems to add a symbol to a symbol table / entry to a hash table, assigning NULL to that variable doesn't remove the name but does cause it's value to be overwritten with NULL,  and unset removes the name from the table.

Is this even close to what's going on?  Does anyone have a better explanation?

Comment: There is also the `is_null` function to test for `null` values.

Comment: That's more or less how it works actually :) setting a variable's value to `null` doesn't remove it from the symbol table.

Comment: If the value for key 'x' in your array is NULL then your first eg. `if (isset($array['x']) && $array['x'] === NULL)` will always return false as `isset()` returns false for null values. So if you want to check if an array key is set and can have null value always use `array_key_exists()`

Comment: @user268396 - is_null will have problems if the variable isn't set/isn't defined.

Comment: @ADmad - Nuts!  You're right.  The array_key_exists is handy and I was looking for the equivalent for general variables.

Comment: I think that what makes this all tricky & confusing is that the various PHP functions seem to confound whether the variable exists, wheather it's null, and whether it's value can't be converted to false/true or not.  

If there was a function like is_defined() which returned true when the variable has an entry in the symbol table, remove_definition to remove it, and then everything else indicated an error if an undefined variable was referenced then this would all be much more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP handles variables much like javascript and other scripting like languages. Since PHP is non-type-safe, it uses exactly what you think it does a robust hash table.

You can think of it containing keys which are the variable names which point to values of those variables, the values can be thought of as strings for the most part. These keys should persist in the scope until no longer needed or once they loose scope. So if you set a key's value to NULL the key would still exist pointing to a value of NULL. However if you would like to completely remove the variable similar to delete in C or Dispose in C#, you would need to use unset or the like and completely remove the key from the hash table.

I hope that answers your question. Let me know if you would like more explanation.